# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь, который авторизовался на главной странице оставался зарегистрированным на всех страницах?

Tags: веб-программирование

Пользователь, который авторизовался на главной странице при переходе на другую страницу становится не авторизованным. Что нужно добавить в код, чтобы исправить это?

Comment: А как вам удалось так сделать? Где вы храните данные об авторизации?

Comment: Я использую сессии для отправки данных. Данные пользователя в таблице БД храню.

Comment: Еще раз - где хранится информация о том, что пользователь авторизовался?

Comment: В переменной вроде

Comment: $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Стартуете сессию и проверяете значение `$_SESSION['logged_user']`

Comment: <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) : ?>
   <span class="js-button-campaign"><?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->user_name; ?></span>
   <?php endif ?>

Comment: я уже так сделал

Comment: Где **Стартуете сессию**?

Comment: для этого нужно указать session_start()?

Comment: Именно так.....

Comment: Это надо сделать в условии if вместо isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])?

Comment: Все сделал, спасибо за ответ